# NodeJS Basic FileIO

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, file-io

Just testing NodeJS out and still learning to think in javascript, how can I get this basic FileIO operation below to work?

Here's what I'd like it to do:

- Read XML file (read into memory)
- Put all contents into a variable
- Write XML file from variable
- Output should be the same as original file

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filepath = 'c:\/testin.xml';

fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.error("Could not open file: %s", err);
    }
});

fs.writeFile('c:\/testout.xml', data, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.error("Could not write file: %s", err);
    }
});
```

Comment: You do not need to escape forward slashes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you try to write the data you read to the target file before it has been read - those operations are asynchronous.

Simply move the file-writing code into the callback of the `readFile` operation:

```
fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.error("Could not open file: %s", err);
        return;
    }
    fs.writeFile('c:/testout.xml', data, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error("Could not write file: %s", err);
        }
    });
});
```

Another option would be using [`readFileSync()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_encoding) - but that would be a bad idea depending on when you do that (e.g. if the oepration is caused by a HTTP request from a user)

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf-8');
fs.writeFileSync('c:/testout.xml', data);
```